Spring csrf protection does not work as expected
I implemented a CustomCsrfTokenRepository to save csrf tokens in a postgres database.
    @Component
public class CustomCsrfTokenRepository implements CsrfTokenRepository {
    private final JpaTokenRepository jpaTokenRepository;

    public CustomCsrfTokenRepository(JpaTokenRepository jpaTokenRepository) {
        this.jpaTokenRepository = jpaTokenRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public CsrfToken generateToken(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        return new DefaultCsrfToken("X-CSRF-TOKEN", "_csrf", uuid);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveToken(CsrfToken csrfToken, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

        String identifier = httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-IDENTIFIER");
        Optional<Token> existingToken =
                jpaTokenRepository.findTokenByIdentifier(identifier);
        if (existingToken.isPresent()) {
            Token token = existingToken.get();
            token.setToken(csrfToken.getToken());
        } else {
            Token token = new Token();
            token.setToken(csrfToken.getToken());
            token.setIdentifier(identifier);
            jpaTokenRepository.save(token);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CsrfToken loadToken(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

        String identifier = httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-IDENTIFIER");
        Optional<Token> existingToken = jpaTokenRepository.findTokenByIdentifier(identifier);
        if (existingToken.isPresent()) {
            Token token = existingToken.get();
            return new DefaultCsrfToken("X-CSRF-TOKEN", "_csrf",
                    token.getToken());
        }
        return null;
    }
}

I configured the application as:
    http.csrf(c -> {
        c.csrfTokenRepository(customTokenRepository);
        c.csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler());
    });

I have 2 endpoints, one is a GET and the other is a POST. When I call the GET endpoint, my csrf token is not written in the database.
curl -k -H "X-IDENTIFIER:123456" https://localhost:8080/hello
Only when I call the post request, do I get the token saved in the database.
curl -k -X POST -H "X-IDENTIFIER:123456" -H "X-CSRF-TOKEN:2bc652f5-258b-4a26-b45" https://localhost:8080/hello
This is looking wrong. I should get the token generated and saved to the database when I call the GET request instead, How can I achieve the right csrf protection?
